# Projections of points onto Angle-bisector

Tags: geometry

Let $\triangle ABC$ have $AB = 15$, $BC = 14$, and $CA=13.$ Let $\ell_1$ be the angle bisector of $\angle ABC$ and let $\ell_2$ be the angle bisector of $\angle BAC.$ If the projection of $B$ onto $\ell_2$ is $Q$ and the projection of $A$ onto $\ell_1$ is $P$ find $PQ$.

---

Let $\ell_1$ and $\ell_2$ intersect at $F$.

Right away, I noticed that $ABPQ$ is cyclic. Thus, it consequently follows that $\triangle PQF \sim \triangle AFB$ so if we can find the similarity ratio then I can find $PQ.$ However, the trouble is I'm not sure how to.

I've tried angle chasing, but it doesn't seem to lead anywhere. I also tried to use angle bisector theorem but it doesn't really relate to $BP$ or $AQ$. The numbers are very ugly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the similarity ratio is $\frac{PF}{AF}=\cos \angle AFP.$

then
\begin{array}{ll}
\dfrac{PF}{AF}=\cos\angle AFP \\
=\cos \left(\frac{1}{2}(\angle BAC+\angle CBA)\right)\\
=\cos \left(\frac{1}{2}(\pi-\angle ACB)\right)\\
=\sin \frac{1}{2}\angle ACB\\
=\sqrt{\dfrac{1-\cos \angle ACB}{2}}\\
=\sqrt{\dfrac{1-(\frac{AC^2+BC^2-AB^2}{2AC\cdot BC})}{2}}\\
=\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{13}}.
\end{array}

then
$$\dfrac{PQ}{AB}=\dfrac{PF}{AF}=\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{13}}.$$
$$PQ = \dfrac{2}{\sqrt{13}} \cdot AB = \dfrac{30}{\sqrt{13}}.$$